# Insert method of Selfmade Ringbuffer not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming and I'm stuck on a certain little project.

The task is to program a kind of ring buffer. I thought that I've solved it, but the `insert()` method does not work as intended.

First, the method inserts a string into the element field of the first element in the array (an Entry object). The idea then is to move every element in an array one index further, after a new element is put in. By doing this the first inserted string will be overwritten when the array is full. Whenever I add new items to the array all elements in the array are the same. For instance, if I add the string `Number1` through this method the result is an array consisting of objects that all hold the string `Number1`.

A little help would be appreciated as I seemingly turned blind to my code.
Here is my code:

```
package k2;

public class Buffer {
//kind of a ringbuffer

    public Entry first;
    public Entry[] grid;
    
    public Buffer(int capacity) {
        this.grid = new Entry[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            this.grid[i] = new Entry(this.grid[(i + 1) % capacity], this.grid[(i + (capacity - 1)) % capacity]);
        }
        this.first = grid[0];
    }
    
    public class Entry { 
//The Entry objects should be linked to each other and hold a string in their element field

        public String element;
        public Entry next;
        public Entry previous;
        
        public Entry(Entry next, Entry previous) { 
            this.element = null;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = next;
        }
    }

    public void insert(String string) {
        grid[0].element = string;
        
        Entry[] grid2 = new Entry[grid.length];
        
                // After adding an element, every item in the array should be moved to the next             index
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
            grid2[(j + 1) % grid.length] = grid[j];
            this.grid = grid2; 
        }
        
        this.print();
    }
    
    public void print() {
        for (Entry element : grid) {
            if (element.element == null) {
                System.out.println("Empty!");
            } 
            else {
            System.out.println(element.element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to change the method, but I can't fix the problem. I tried to solve it on paper as well and for me, everything seems just right.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your For-Loop. Why?
Because, lets make it simple and go with numbers. lets say your Array contains:
1,2,3,4,etc. Now you are adding 0. You will add 0 in the first spot then you will push the first spot to the second spot. Next you iterate to the second spot. This spot is already the content of firstspot e.g. already is 0, so you already lost your  content 2. Then you push this 0 to the 3rd spot and so on. Thats why you got everywhere the same Entry.

Try this.

```java
public void insert(String string) {
    //Buffer for updating Array
    Entry Buffer = grid[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        //Shifting all Entrys one index higher
        Entry tmp = grid[i + 1];
        grid[i + 1] = Buffer;
        Buffer = tmp;
    }

    //Set previous and next to the updated 2nd and last Entry
    grid[0] = new Entry(grid[1], grid[grid.length - 1]);
    grid[0].element = string;

    this.print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried it out with your annotations and now it works!